# Sorting with date and minimum time in R

Tags: r, date, time

This task is difficult for me. I need to find the temp value for every one hour (minimum recorded time) of 30/31 days of a month. But, the sensor is measured the temp value at irregular periods (input file is attached as image). I want to write R code for this. Eg output:

```
1/6/2016 0.00 90.45
1/6/2016 1.01 92.54
1/6/2016 2.12 94.95

1/6/2016 21.53 95.85
```

[image]

A similar sample data frame:

> sample <- 
>     data.frame(
>       date = c(rep("2016-06-01", 13), NA, NA, rep("2016-06-01", 3), NA, NA, rep("2016-06-01", 3), NA, rep("2016-06-02", 2)),
>       time = c("0:00", "0:10", "0:20", "0:30", "1:01", "1:11", "1:21", "1:31", "1:41", "1:51", "2:12", "2:42", "2:52", NA, NA, "12:03", "12:13", "12:23", NA, NA, "21:53", "21:54", "23:14", NA, NA, NA),
>       temp = c(90.45, 91.29, 90.88, 91.22, 92.54, 92.57, 93.18, 93.9, 94.51, 94.37, 95.96, 95.32, 95.2, NA, NA, 95.37, 95.52, 95.35, NA, NA, 95.85, 95.6, 96.14, NA, NA, NA)
>     )

If anyone please help of How to do with R programming

Comment: You can use `cut.POSIXct` to cut the time into hourly intervals, use that as grouping variable to find the minimum value

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: thanks @akrun. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: It is already posted as a solution by Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on akrun's suggestion, here's a potential implementation using cut.POSIXct and dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
 output <- 
  sample %>% # Using reproducible dataset above
  # Filter to only observed records
  filter(!is.na(date) & !is.na(time)) %>% 
  mutate(
    # Create a date_time using the date and time variables
    date_time = as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), 
                format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
    # Create hour intervals to be used as grouping variable 
         hour    = cut.POSIXt(date_time, breaks = "hour")) %>%
  # Group by hour
  group_by(hour) %>%
  # Select only records where the date and time are the minimum
  # date and time in the group
  filter(date_time == min(date_time))
```

I annotated the code -- there are definitely ways to make the code more concise and/or handle edge-cases like the empty records better, but this should correctly select the minimum date-time per hour.

Comment: Thanks Adam. But I am newbie to R programming. Can you please elaborate the code in full, so that I can get the complete result.         library(dplyr)
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/june")
data<-read.csv("test.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    Do I need to write your code after input file path. How to save the output with the sensor value... Kindly reply me.

Comment: No problem. Assuming that's how you're loading the non-sample data (as 'data'), you'd need to run the code to read the file in and then run the code I wrote switching out line three ('sample %>%' becomes 'data %>%')

Comment: library(dplyr)
    data <- read.csv("test.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
    output <- 
      data %>%
      filter(!is.na(date) & !is.na(time)) %>% 
      mutate(
        date_time = as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), 
                format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
        hour    = cut.POSIXt(date_time, breaks = "hour")) %>%
    group_by(hour) %>%
    filter(date_time == min(date_time))

Comment: Thanks Adam so much...awesome

Comment: > output <- 
+   data %>%
+ filter(!is.na(Date) & !is.na(Time)) %>% 
+   mutate(
+ date_time = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), 
+                            format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
+ hour = cut.POSIXt(date_time, breaks = "hour")) %>%
+ group_by(hour) %>%
+ filter(date_time == min(date_time))

Comment: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min.default(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max.default(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Dear Adam. When I execute the last line,  I am getting the above mentioned error

Comment: Quick glance, it looks like you've  got one of three things:
    - a missing pipe;
    - missing (NA) values that aren't being handled by the filters; or
    - an incorrectly typed variable (eg. something is a string where it should be numeric (ex. [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709973/error-in-seq-defaultfrom-minx-na-rm-true-to-maxx-na-rm-true))