# R selective finite number error when applying log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm aiming to plot a large dataset with a log scale, but keep receiving the following error:

```
Error in seq.default(min, max, by = by) : 'from' must be a finite number
```

I've attempted some approaches below, but still receive the same error:

- converting the relevant values to numeric values (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34710162/7681828)
- adding a small value to all values (i.e. 1e-8) to avoid infinites (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/7wjkA60cWb)

My code/working is as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.2
library(reprex)

# Subset original data with dput
data <- structure(list(
  x = c(500, 525, 500, 525), 
  y = as.numeric(
    c(0.070860012, 0.052973494, 
      6.91685849999998e-310,
      4.68262549999999e-310))), 
  row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# View data
data
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       x         y
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1   500 7.09e-  2
#> 2   525 5.30e-  2
#> 3   500 6.92e-310
#> 4   525 4.68e-310

# Error when plotting with log scale
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_log10()
#> Error in seq.default(min, max, by = by): 'from' must be a finite number

# Check values are finite
is.finite(data$y)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

# Works fine without log scale
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```r
# Works fine with no duplicate x
ggplot(data %>% slice(1:2),
       aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

```r
# Reproducible example may suggest an issue with the y values in data
rep <- data.frame(
  x = sample(c(500, 525, 500, 525)),
  y = runif(4, max = 1e-300))

# Plotting the reprex with log scale doesn't throw an error
ggplot(rep, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any insight to why this the error is occurring or alternative approaches are much appreciated!

Comment: It's a bug and discussed here https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2876  https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR/pull/56/commits/0bb56693fcf90d967050f6328e4c255b9f762bfa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're really close to the exponent limit of R, and specifically this seems to be a floating point error.  See the following example of my exchange with the R console:

```
> 1e-310
[1] 1e-310   # seems ok
> 1e-315
[1] 1e-315   # seems ok
> 1e-320
[1] 9.999889e-321  # hm... seems like floating point error
> 1e-324
[1] 0   # R gives up.
```

This means that it's just... not possible to plot a point with a value around 1e-324 or so.  However, 1e-310 seems ok... so why can't we plot that?  Is R or `ggplot` somehow trying to access numbers around 1e-324?  Actually, the answer is "yes".

`ggplot` always expands the plot area a bit past the limits of the plot, which in this case would include a lower limit of your Xe-310 number.  If that's the case that the expansion is causing the issue, we should be able to get around this by removing the expansion of the plot along that axis, which works:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_y_log10(expand=c(0.04,0))
```

[image]

Interesting, the default `expand=` is 0.05, from what I understand.  When you input that as your lower expansion, you get the error again:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_y_log10(expand=c(0.05,0))

Error in seq.default(min, max, by = by) : 'from' must be a finite number
```